# What's the JavaScript equivalent of CSS Media Queries?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm experienced in using media queries to target CSS to specific browser sizes/or contexts, but now I'm interested in doing this with JS, essentially having more control over how my scripts run on browsers of different abilities.

I'm not asking for how to duplicate the functionality of media queries in JS, but more what are the methods for controlling which code gets run on which browsers?

Is there a method or system that would give me this control without resorting to detecting browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't anything to control how where your code is run unless you do some ground work in detecting the situations you want the code to run in and wrapping things in if blocks. You can use conditional statements in HTML, if blocks in your generating server code, or in the js itself.

Answer (score 1):

multiple `if` statements:

```
if ($(window).width() > 900)) {
   // do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. I'm not so interested in duplicating the function of media queries in JS, but more looking for the logical control equivalent allowing me to manage how/where my code gets run.

Answer (score 0):

4+ levels of indirection are not necessary.

```
var width = typeof innerWidth === 'undefined' ? document.body.clientWidth : innerWidth;
if (width > 900) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to define breakpoints for a responsive design, and then will fire custom events when the browser enters and/or exits that breakpoint.

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/